# How do I toogle sidebars?

Tags: javascript

I've got a sliding panel which I want to hide in push.
Now I've got two links, one for show and another for hide:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

How can I do it in one function ?

Comment: In one function... You mean click once to open and then to close?

Comment: have you considered using classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer**

Below is a simple way to do it with minimal change from your code:

```
function toggleNav() {
  if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width === "0") {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  }
}
```

**A better approach using CSS**

This approach will greatly reduce the complexity of the JS. If you attached a `nav-open` class to a parent container such as the document body.

JS

```
function toggleNav() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-open');
}
```

CSS

```
.nav-open #mySidenav {
  width: 250px;
}

.nav-open #main {
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a variable like so:

```js
var navIsOpen = false;

function toggleNav() {
  if (navIsOpen) {
    // Close
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  } else {
    // Open
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }

  navIsOpen = !navIsOpen;
}
```